# Clear TextFormField's text returns error string because autovalidation

Tags: flutter

Here is my code,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final appTitle = 'Form Validation Demo';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: appTitle,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(appTitle),
        ),
        body: MyCustomForm(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

// Create a Form widget.
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  //
  // Note: This is a GlobalKey<FormState>,
  // not a GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  
  final myController = TextEditingController();
  final myController1 = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
            controller: myController,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction
          ),
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
            controller: myController1,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false
                // otherwise.
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
                  myController.clear(); 
                  myController1.clear(); 
                  Scaffold.of(context)
                      .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Successfully saved')));
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On Submit button click I need to clear the form for new data. When I do that the text fields are marked as error because of autovalidation. Any idea on how to solve this? I need both auto validation, but when I submit, I need to clear the form for new data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textfields are not really marked as error. They just give the text because you stated in your code that they should give an errorText if the textfield is empty, which they are when you clear the textfield. If you want to use that errorCode than that will always be the case, unless you completely trigger a rebuild after the clearing of your ControlEditors. If someone types something and deletes it, the validator will still be triggered.

```
validator: (value) {
          if (value.isEmpty) {
            return 'Please enter some text';
          }
          return null;
        },
```

If you dont want to have an error then you need to take another validation route:

```
 if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    print("validation is true");
                    if (myController.text.isNotEmpty &&
                        myController1.text.isNotEmpty) {
                      myController.clear();
                      myController1.clear();

                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text('Successfully saved'),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        SnackBar(
                          content: Text(
                            'ERROR, field cannot be empty! Enter some text',
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  } else {
                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(
                        content: Text(
                          'ERROR, validation failed',
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
```

You cannot have it both ways... But I think that should do the same as what you want.

**EDIT:** Other way:

```
Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false
                  // otherwise.

                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
                    setState(() {
                      _formKey.currentState.reset();
                    });

                    myController.clear();
                    myController1.clear();

                    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                      SnackBar(
                        content: Text('Successfully saved'),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Actually I want the case `If someone types something and deletes it, the validator will still need to be triggered.` And also want to clear the form once everything is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, here auto validation is turned off when the user tap the submit button, and later if the user taps on the textfile the auto validation is turned back on

```
class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyCustomFormState createState() {
    return MyCustomFormState();
  }
}

// Create a corresponding State class.
// This class holds data related to the form.
class MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  // Create a global key that uniquely identifies the Form widget
  // and allows validation of the form.
  //
  // Note: This is a GlobalKey<FormState>,
  // not a GlobalKey<MyCustomFormState>.
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  final myController = TextEditingController();
  final myController1 = TextEditingController();

  bool autoValidate = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Build a Form widget using the _formKey created above.
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
            controller: myController,
            autovalidateMode: autoValidate
                ? AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction
                : AutovalidateMode.disabled,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                autoValidate = true;
              });
            },
          ),
          TextFormField(
            validator: (value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter some text';
              }
              return null;
            },
            controller: myController1,
            autovalidateMode: autoValidate
                ? AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction
                : AutovalidateMode.disabled,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                autoValidate = true;
              });
            },
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Validate returns true if the form is valid, or false
                // otherwise.
                if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                  // If the form is valid, display a Snackbar.
                  myController.clear();
                  myController1.clear();
                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    SnackBar(
                      content: Text('Successfully saved'),
                    ),
                  );
                  setState(() {
                    autoValidate = false;
                  });
                }
              },
              child: Text('Submit'),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```